# Prolog: duplicated family member

Tags: prolog

I have the following prolog code:

```
man(otto).
man(horst).
man(dieter).
man(hans).
man(stefan).
man(martin).

woman(gerda).
woman(ursula).
woman(petra).
woman(susann).

father(otto, dieter).
father(otto, hans).
father(horst, susann).
father(dieter, stefan).
father(dieter, martin).

mother(gerda, dieter).
mother(gerda, hans).
mother(ursula, susann).
mother(petra, stefan).
mother(susann, martin).

parent(Father, Child) :- father(Father, Child).
parent(Mutter, Child) :- mother(Mutter, Child).
child(Child, Parent) :- parent(Parent, Child).

grantparent(Grantparent, Grantchild) :-
  parent(Grantparent, Child),
  parent(Child, Grantchild).

grantchild(Grantchild, Grantparent) :- grantparent(Grantparent, Grantchild).

son(Son, Parent) :-
  parent(Parent, Son),
  man(Son).

daughter(Daughter, Parent) :-
  parent(Parent, Daughter),
  woman(Daughter).

brother(Brother, Sibling) :-
  parent(Parent, Brother),
  parent(Parent, Sibling),
  man(Brother),
  Brother \== Sibling.

uncle(Uncle, Person) :-
  bruder(Uncle, Parent),
  parent(Parent, Person).
```

The most of my queries match. But when I try to figure out what the brother of 'dieter' is, 'hans' will be printed two times.

```
?- brother(dieter, Brother).
Brother = hans ;
Brother = hans ;
false.
```

Also when I ask, what is the uncle of 'martin'.

```
?- uncle(Uncle, martin).
Uncle = hans ;
Uncle = hans ;
false.
```

Can you help and tell me what's the problem with my family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parent/2` predicate will cause duplicate, since:

```
father(otto, dieter),
father(otto, hans).
```

holds, and;

```
mother(gerda, dieter),
mother(gerda, hans).
```

Holds. This will thus result two possible traces where `dieter` and `hans` are brothers.

If the families are "*simple*" families, where there are no *half siblings*. You can pick one of the two. For example:

```
brother(Brother, Sibling) :-
    father(Parent, Brother),
    father(Parent, Sibling),
    man(Brother),
    Brother \== Sibling.
```

If you want to exclude half-siblings, you should, like you say yourself, check both the father and the mother:

```
brother(Brother, Sibling) :-
    father(Father, Brother),
    father(Father, Sibling),
    mother(Mother, Brother),
    mother(Mother, Sibling),
    man(Brother),
    Brother \== Sibling.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's it.

Comment: I tried around a bit and I'm a bit confused. hans and dieter aren't half siblings. They have the same parents: otto and gerda. Only martin an stefan are half siblings - the two sons of dieter.
And: Isn't it better to exclude all of the half siblings like that:

    brother(Brother, Sibling) :-
      father(Father, Brother),
      father(Father, Sibling),
      mother(Mother, Brother),
      mother(Mother, Sibling),
      man(Brother),
      Brother \== Sibling.

Comment: @marwils: yes, that is an option as well. If you want to exclude the half-sliblings, you should check the two paths.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to define `siblings/2` as

```
siblings(S1, S2) :-
    parent(P, S1),
    parent(P, S2),
    S1 @< S2.
```

This avoids generating both `siblings(dieter,hans)` and `siblings(hans,dieter)`.

(The `brother/2` relation can then be defined using `siblings/2`.)